# Spotted fast, VERY bright, moving object in the sky tonight in Gex, France

Tags: planet

Tonight around midnight, I spotted a very bright moving object in the sky. Confused and intrigued with my sighting, I decided to go on google to find some answers. It clearly was not a plane as it was far to bright and did not flash. It was not a shooting star as it was not as fast and moved for around 1 minute in the sky before disappearing. I firmly believe it was not a satellite as it was, again, really too bright (and I had spotted 3 other satellites prior to this, it really did not compare). After searching around on various forums describing similar sightings, many people suggested it could have b ISS. However, after checking it’s location today (July 24-25 (23:59-00:00) it was over Australia, meaning I would not have been able to see it.

I even checked websites regarding possibilities that it may have been Jupiter, Saturn or even Mars as they a notorious for being particularly bright during the July-August period. However, pardon my lack of astronomy knowledge, I assume they would not be moving at such a high speeds. I also checked a star map showing their locations, at this moment in time they are facing south and the object I spotted was facing east.

This leads me to my final point. The only evidence I found online which resembles my sighting was similar to this mans sighting in his video: (https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-3410791/What-bright-object-flying-sky-Man-claims-filmed-UFO-Florida.html)

However, when I spotted “this” object, it was not at all green but a bright, white light. He also refers to his sighting as a ‘UFO’ and I personally don’t believe in aliens hovering around earth in little spaceships.

Does anyone have any idea what it could have been? I am very curious about this now.

Thank you!

*edit: to the kind stranger who suggested the other forum post as a possible solution (Star like light moving in the sky, what could it be? [closed]) what he describes is not the same, the object was as bright as the brightest star in the sky that night, and travelled over the whole stretch of the sky that I could see, it came over the Jura mountain range and vanished towards the Alps

Comment: Are you sure about the exactitude of the hour ? The travel time for ISS from France to Australia is around 45 minutes (and it is a possible trajectory for ISS).

Comment: What he describes is not the same (check post edit)

Comment: Perhaps not, but the answer is the same: A moving light is not an astrononmical object. It was either, a misidentification of a non-moving object, or a plane/satelite/drone/lantern, or an illusion, or fraud.  I'd guess it was the ISS and your timing is wrong, but I don't know.